# Cannot change multiple objects to the same absolute value in Illustrator 23.0.3

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

Example:

I'm trying to edit the rightmost column of squares (below) so they all have the same x value.

[image]

However when I try to edit their values as a group selection, it does not alter their values to the new position.

[image]

[image]

Without doing this manually, what's the best way to convert multiple different values to the same absolute value in Illustrator?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. In the Align panel, choose Horizontal Align Center, then you can set the x position of the group.

Comment: You need to either move them individually, or use the align tool. Also, it looks like you have a messed up lower left corner on the center row. Good luck.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi thank you both for your replies! Yep clicking horizontal align centre solved it.

Comment: @13ruce oh yeah, good eye! thanks haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Align panel (**Window → Align** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>).

Select the objects you want to be aligned then click preferable align type.

<sup>Sorry for Swedish in the pictures but I think you can figure it out.</sup>

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi thank you this worked perfectly! Glad to see icons look the same in Swedish :)